# No transform from [right_leg] to [/base_link]

Tags: ros, urdf, urdf-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was developing my URDF robot model, using [ros tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch) as reference, and got my second error (the first was [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/1725/no-transform-from-base_link-to-map)).

I'm using exactly multipleshapes example, but when I try it, this error happens:
"right_leg
No transform from [right_leg] to [/base_link]"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10782/no-transform-from-%5Bright_leg%5D-to-%5B/base_link%5D/) by [Vinipsmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/912/vinipsmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should try out some of the debugging approaches laid out in the tf wiki [troubleshooting page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Troubleshooting).

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinipsmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/912/vinipsmaker/) on 2011-08-02**:
Okay, I'll debug, but I'm using the same code as the tutorial. It MUST work. The tutorial can't teach us wrong. NOTE: I can't install the urdf_tutorial package, so I'm running using the simples command "rosrun rviz rviz"

**Comment by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) on 2014-11-21**:
@Vinipsmaker. I ran into the same problem when doing the tutorial. Did you ever manage to figure out what went wrong? I tried to debug but tf_echo gives no output and tf_monitor says "tf_monitor waiting for time to be published". I use Indigo btw.